# Using electron-boilerplate to create an .exe for windows. It needs to run a .bat file. Once it's packaged, it doesn't run

Tags: electron, child-process

Using the electron-boilerplate to create an .exe for windows, it needs to run a .bat file. However, using npm start it works but when it gets packaged with npm run release, it doesn't run the .bat

This is my code for the function

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'Install.bat']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    addLog(data);
    console.info(str);
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    addLog(data,"error");
    console.error(str); 
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`Exit ${code}`);
});
```

Already checked for child-process

Comment: Is `cmd.exe` in the same directory as your electron app? It could be a path issue.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to install the electron-boilerplate folder in the Windows SYSTEM 32 path? My folder is in C

Comment: Already added the cmd.exe to the electron-boilerplate folder and still not working

Comment: I'll take that as "yes". I wasn't suggesting a fix, just asking for more info before I attempt to answer. Answer to follow shortly

Answer (score 0):

When you run electron via `npm start` it will typically set the current working directory to the folder for the app (containing your package.json). So it will look for `cmd.exe` in that folder.

After you build the app and run it, the current working directory might be somewhere else, for example `C:\\` (on Windows). You can find the current working directory with `process.cwd()`.

To find the app folder regardless of how the app is running, Electron provides `electron.app.getAppPath()`.

So you can use it like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const cmdPath = path.join(electron.app.getAppPath(),'cmd.exe');
const bat = spawn(cmdPath, ['/c', 'Install.bat']);
```

Comment: Okay so I edited my code, however when I do "npm run release", the file isn't working and the .bat doesn't run

Comment: const path = require('path');
const cmdPath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'cmd.exe');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;const bat = spawn(cmdPath, ['/c','Install.bat']);